# Conditional types for nullable in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, conditional-statements, nullable

I want to check if a type is nullable or not, and if it has a conditional type on the value.

I tried implementing

```
type IsNullable<T> = T extends null ? true : false;
```

However, it does not seem to work

```
type test = IsNullable<number> // Returns false as it should
type test = IsNullable<number | null> // Returns false when it should be true
```

What's the proper way of checking if a type is nullable? I tried with `T extends null | T` and did not work either.

Comment: try to flip condiction as suggested here 
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29627

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can switch the left and right side of the `extends`, so

```
type IsNullable<T> = null extends T ? true : false;
```

should work for you.

Comment: No, it does not work as `IsNullable<number>` returns true. However if I change from `IsBoolean<T> = boolean extends T ? true : false` then it works. It seems everything extends null?

Comment: @Marc, it does work. Make sure `strictNullChecks` enabled. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgzgOQK4BsUEMBGKIB4AqAfFALxQB2qKUEAHsBOQCZxT5QD8UwATktAC4oAM3Qo4EANwAoAPSzu4aAzjBSsRFSw5clALaYIPQtNCRuEVevjI02vPsM8oAHwpVCkoA)

Comment: Yes, @AlekseyL. has a good point there. If you do not enable `strictNullChecks` in your `tsconfig.json`, every type extends null.
You should really set `strict: null` there.