# Can return types be conditionally null in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I want this function to conditionally return a nullable type if it's given a nullable `TGoalType` or a non-nullable version of that type if it is supplied a non-nullable type.

```
function mapGoalType<TGoalType extends IParentGoal | undefined>(
  parentGoal: TGoalType
): null extends TGoalType ? MultiSelectOption | null : MultiSelectOption {
  if (!parentGoal) {
    return null; // Typescript complains here
  }
...
}
```

I tried code that is similar to [Conditional types for nullable in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59626785/conditional-types-for-nullable-in-typescript) but TypeScript isn't cooperating as it complains that I can't return null for a non-nullable return type. Is there a way to get TypeScript to understand what I want?

Comment: This is one of those cases where you want type narrowing to apply to a type parameter. Unfortunately, type narrowing only applies to variables and properties. If Typescript could figure out that when `parentGoal` is falsy, `null` must be assignable to `TGoalType`, then there would be no problem. (I'm assuming there are no other falsy values which could be assignable to `IParentGoal`.)

Comment: The code here doesn't seem to be a [mcve] so I can't be sure, but the issue is the same as in the other question and [its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59905652/2887218); the compiler cannot narrow generic type parameters via control flow analysis (see [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912)).  For now you will have to use a type assertion (like `return null as null extends TGoalType ? MultiSelectOption | null : MultiSelectOption`) or a single-call-signature overload to suppress the error.